# Issue with $.browser.typekit

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

After a day long research for a nice smooth scrolling I found this beautiful small code that results in a super smooth scrolling page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
    easeOutQuint: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t * t * t + 1) + b;
    }
});

var wheel = false,
    $docH = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
    $scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if (wheel === false) {
        $scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    }
});
$(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {
    delta = delta || -e.originalEvent.detail / 3 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120;
    wheel = true;

    $scrollTop = Math.min($docH, Math.max(0, parseInt($scrollTop - delta * 30)));
    $($.browser.webkit ? 'body' : 'html').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $scrollTop + 'px'
    }, 2000, 'easeOutQuint', function() {
        wheel = false;
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

The issue I'm facing is that the $.browser has been removed since jQuery 1.9.
I have tried to find a workaround to make this work with a newer version of it without any results. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Migrate.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

It has all the APIs and features removed from jQuery core.

JQuery browser is in there. See here:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/src/core.js#L83

Here is another link from JQuery telling you that you can use JQuery Migrate but it'd be better if you used something like Modernizr.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

To use it just include it in your code like so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Johnston. Isn't there any kind of "replacement" for browser in any of the new versions?

Comment: @Jaypee Use Modernizr. But if you want that function available specifically you would use jquery migrate. That is exactly what is for. Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

After continuing my research I found the a code to successfully create the smooth scrolling without the need to migrate jquery. It seems to work perfectly across all browsers. [The code was found here](http://forrst.com/posts/Smooth_Scrolling_like_Parallax-Gor)

I have tested it with 1.11 and 2.1 versions.

The Code:

```
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
    else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

    handle(delta);
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}

function handle(delta) {
    var time = 1000;
    var distance = 200;
    // Dom where it will apply 
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() - (distance * delta)
    }, time );
}
```

Hope this helps to anyone looking to solve this same issue.